Finding the global maximum to a non-convex, non-linear function of many variables
I have the log-likelihood of a probability distribution I need to maximise:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{L} \text{coeffsA}[i] \cdot \log(x[i]) + 
\sum_{i=1}^{L} \text{coeffsB}[i] \cdot \log\left(x[i + L]\right) + \\
\sum_{i \neq j} 
\log\left(\frac{1 - (x[i] \cdot x[j])}{1 - (x[i] \cdot x[j]) + (x[i + L] \cdot x[j + L] \cdot x[i] \cdot x[j])}\right)
$$
where $\text{coeffsA}[i]$ and $\text{coeffsB}[i]$ are some non-negative integers for $i \in \{1,2,\dots,L\}$, which can be quite large, and $x[i]$ is a variable i.e. $x_i$ for $i \in \{1,2,\dots,2L\}$. I am constraining $0 \leq x_i \leq 1$, though technically I should put can have $0 \leq x_i x_j < 1$ for all $i,j$, but its proving best to relax this.
I have been able to use global optimisers like BARON on this, but it is failing to give me the global optimum. I am aware of what the optimium should be as the decision variables $x$ solve a system of equations (see Unbiased sampling of network ensembles, Squartini et al. 2015), so I can solve with BARON then check if they indeed solve these equations.
The problem is even for small L like $L=10$, so a simple small network case, that should be simple to optimise, I am not getting the global optimum. I have gotten close to it with local solvers like nlopt in python, but its still not global.
I ultimately need this optimised for $L=10,000$, with coefficients which can be as large as $10^6$.
Can anyone advise what I can do to get a global optimum for a function like this? I have tried rescaling, testing the  system with very simple coefficients, running for a long time, many different solvers, but all see this function as a nightmare to optimise, despite it following from a famous probability problem (sampling from the configuration model of random graphs).

$0 \leq x_i \leq 1$ is not a relaxation of $0 \leq x_i x_j < 1$. Rather, it overconstrains. I.e., unless you know there is a global optimum having $0 \leq x_i \leq 1$, you might be cutting off the global optimum. Also, bad problem scaling can cause BARON to not find the true global optimum, even if it reports it has found it.

Thank you that is a good pointer, the thing is there are millions of these $x_i x_j$ terms, so it is either overloading the memory or running very slowly, so it seems almost impossible not to put "simpler" constraints, but still I will try and insist on using the proper constraints on simple test versions with few variables.

I think BARON is better than nlopt at handling many constraints. It was asking for 700GB of virtual memory in python before I turned to BARON.

SCIP can solve non-convex MINLPs to global optimality, but I don't know if it would compare well with BARON performance-wise. In case you want to try it in Python, there is PySCIPOpt.
